# How to get mouse selected text from Jupyter text widget?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I want to capture the mouse selected text from a jupyter text widget .

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
text = widgets.Textarea(
    value='Hello World',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)
display(text)
```

In the following example when **World** is selected and left click is complete then I want to capture the  text highlighted .

[image]

Comment: I don't believe it is possible to get the selected portion of text from ipywidgets.

Answer (score 5):

With a JS you can add listener on `select` event of the original `text` widget. Then the selected text is copied into a `sel_text` widget. Finally you can access it through the `sel_text.value`

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import Javascript

ta_description = 'String:'
text = widgets.Textarea(
    value='Hello big World',
    description=ta_description,
    disabled=False
)
sel_text = widgets.Text(
    value='',
    description='selected text:',
    disabled=True
)
display(text, sel_text)

jscript = f'''

function put2widget(arg) {{
    var manager = window.IPython.WidgetManager._managers[0];
    var ta = manager.get_model('{sel_text.model_id}');
    ta.then(function(model) {{
        model.set('value', arg)
        model.save()
    }});
}}

function getSelection(event) {{
  const selection = event.target.value.substring(event.target.selectionStart, event.target.selectionEnd);
  put2widget(selection)

}}

const area = document.querySelectorAll('label[title="{ta_description}"]')[0].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]
area.addEventListener("select", getSelection); 

'''

Javascript(jscript)
```

Answer (score -1):

There no way to capture or print the mouse selected keyword in Jupyter.